# javascript exception:object expected without any reason

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am writing a webesite and I'm using javascript in my code,befor I have used it in my code and is was working successfully!but now suddenly it doesn't work and it says object expected!I don't know where is the problem,because it was working befor!
this is the poece of my code:

```
    <script  type="text/javascript"src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var interval = setInterval(time, 1000);
    }); // ending ')' was missing
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function time() {
        var date = new Date();
        var hour = date.getHours();
        var min = date.getMinutes();
        var sec = date.getSeconds();

        $('#time2').val(hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec);


    }
</script>'
```

the time2 in and input;but now it doesn't show any thing!!!!with error:object expected

Comment: first of all give us some code that is creating an error, second what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The problem is ..it is expecting a object and you are not providing it

Comment: You definitely need to attach your code

Comment: What kind of element is `#time2`?

Comment: Here's a working example http://jsbin.com/uhocih/1/edit, could you try to replicate your problem and send us the link?

Comment: it's an input with runat="server"

Comment: input !== input (it might be a checkbox), is it `type="text"`?

Comment: @Sarah classic ASP does not have `runat="server"` for elements so it's meaningless. Anyway the code you posted can't possibly cause "object expected" error which means the problem is elsewhere, in code you did not post. Can you see the error with modern browser having JavaScript console and see what exact line is causing it?